# Google Maps API (JS V3) - progressive loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There is a possibility to load markers gradually? I have many markers and map always waits until there all add up, and then suddenly appears. I want to add markers gradually.

For example:

```
map.addMarker({});
sleep(500);
map.addMarker({});
sleep(500);
map.addMarker({});
```

I have to wait until 1000 ms and then the markers appear. I believe You understand what I mean.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi you can use set interval here

Comment: See [this example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration)

Comment: @geocodezip Ha, that's awesome, thanks - I will try it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hi you can use set interval for this like below:-     

addressArray.forEach(function(element, index, array){
        delay += 800;       
        setTimeout(function() {
        //Your code here

        }, delay);

      });
```

Comment: I know about setinterval and also settimeout, but this does not working (i try it for the first time and also now ) 

{foreach $markers as $marker}
    setTimeout(function(){
        addMarker({$marker});
    }, 10000);
{/foreach}

1. sec - map shows up
2,3,4,5,6,7.... 50 - all markers shows up.. so i think this is not the right way

Comment: Ok, I just need to always change the delay... my bad :-) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.delay()` method in association with the marquer ID; or add a `.queue()/.dequeue()` function if you have jquery installed.